# How to save a file in android SDstorage, but my image is not save on location

Tags: android, android-file

File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"myimage.png");

How to save a file in android SDstorage, but my image is not save on location, i have tried my best
Now I'm assuming that I'm not able to create directory automatically this way.

Can someone suggest how to create a directory and sub-directory via code?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageButton= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isExternalStorageWriteable()){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.beautyofpakistan);

            File filepath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"myimage.png");
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"File Saved!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"SDcard not supported!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



    }
    public boolean isExternalStorageWriteable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: The downloads directory mostly already exists. So you do not have to create it. Not that you are trying... You can of course check by code if the directory exists. Which you are not doing either.  If the FileOutputStream cannot create a file then you will have an exception. You should of course place Toast()'s in every catch block you have. Inform the user! And yourself!

Comment: .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is NEVER on a removable SD card though.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this,"File Saved!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. That is on the wrong place. Because even if there was a catch you display this toast. Please adapt the code.

Comment: `Can someone suggest how to create a directory and sub-directory via code?`. You better first concentrate on just saving a file in the Downloads directory. Please add all the code i suggested.